# Google StreetView API extracts images froom indoors. How to fix it?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-cloud-platform, google-street-view

Google StreetView API returns home interior images. For example: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=480x300&location=49.602363,6.133369&key=YOUR-API-KEY

but I would like only street pictures. How can I fix this?

Comment: What about reading the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/intro?hl=fr#optional-parameters)? `source` has `default` or `outdoor` params.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `source=outdoor` to get outdoor images. E.g.:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=480x300&location=49.602363,6.133369&source=outdoor&key=KEY

[Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/intro?hl=fr#optional-parameters) states:

> `source` (default is default) limits Street View searches to selected
>   sources. Valid values are:
>
> - `default` uses the default sources for Street View; searches are not limited to specific sources.
> - `outdoor` limits searches to outdoor collections. Indoor collections are not included in search results. Note that outdoor panoramas may
>     not exist for the specified location. Also note that the search only
>     returns panoramas where it's possible to determine whether they're
>     indoors or outdoors. For example, PhotoSpheres are not returned
>     because it's unknown whether they are indoors or outdoors.

Hope this helps.